# Projection of oblique segment onto another

Tags: geometry

How can I find the length of segment *a*, given the length of segment *b*, and given that the angle between *a* and *b* is *x*?

Alternatively, how can I find the length of segment *a*, given *r* and angle *y*?

OBS: segments *r* and *b* are perpendicular.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's impossible to express a in terms of x and b or y and r. You need 3 of them.

[image]

Comment: Those are what i used? There is also $a= r / \sin(90-x+y) * \sin(y)$

Comment: Thank you, that's what I was looking for.

Answer (score 4):

(a) You cannot find $a$ with only $b$ and $x$ given. There are infinitely many possible figures can be drawn.

[image]

(a) You cannot find $a$ with only $y$ and $r$ given. Again, there are infinitely many possible figures can be drawn.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

For the second problem -- given $y$, $r$, $b$, and $r$ and $b$ perpendicular, find the length of segment $a$ -- there is no solution. In particular, there may be two different lengths $a$ that satisfy the question asked, as in the following diagram, where both $u$ and $v$ are possible solutions:
[image]